# VB.NET Bucle PINVOKE GetKeyState

Tags: vb.net

Tengo algún error en el siguiente bucle y no se cual es ya que no devuelve ningún error, simplemente se queda colgado..

```
While GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString <> "-127" Or GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString <> "-128"
    If GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString = "-127" Or GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString = "-128" Then
        PosMouse.Text = "OK"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End While
```

Tengo 2 programas: listen.exe y main.exe

Al pulsar un botón del programa listen.exe, se activará el bucle, para que cuando se pulse "INSERT" en el programa main.exe, se grabe la posición del ratón.

Con lo que más adelante podré mover el mouse a esa posición.

He salido del apuro con un timer pero tengo curiosidad por la solución...

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con ese bucle es que es posible que bloquee el ui, de tal manera que los eventos del formulario no se procesan, con lo que realmente nunca se leerá la pulsación del teclado.

Una solución muy sencilla para comprobar si es eso es meter un `Application.DoEvents()` dentro del bucle:

```
While GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString <> "-127" Or GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString <> "-128"
    If GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString = "-127" Or GetKeyState(Keys.Insert).ToString = "-128" Then
        PosMouse.Text = "OK"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

Pero lo normal es que ese código esté en otro hilo, usando `BackGroundWorker` o `Task`